# t-SNE predictions in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

**Goal**: I aim to use t-SNE (t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) in R for dimensionality reduction of my training data (with *N* observations and *K* variables, where *K>>N*) and subsequently aim to come up with the t-SNE representation for my test data.

**Example**: Suppose I aim to reduce the K variables to *D=2* dimensions (often, *D=2* or *D=3* for t-SNE). There are two R packages: `Rtsne` and `tsne`, while I use the former here.

```
# load packages
library(Rtsne)

# Generate Training Data: random standard normal matrix with J=400 variables and N=100 observations
x.train <- matrix(nrom(n=40000, mean=0, sd=1), nrow=100, ncol=400)

# Generate Test Data: random standard normal vector with N=1 observation for J=400 variables
x.test <- rnorm(n=400, mean=0, sd=1)

# perform t-SNE
set.seed(1)
fit.tsne <- Rtsne(X=x.train, dims=2)
```

where the command `fit.tsne$Y` will return the (100x2)-dimensional object containing the t-SNE representation of the data; can also be plotted via `plot(fit.tsne$Y)`.

**Problem**: Now, what I am looking for is a function that returns a prediction `pred` of dimension (1x2) for my test data based on the trained t-SNE model. Something like,

```
# The function I am looking for (but doesn't exist yet):
pred <- predict(object=fit.tsne, newdata=x.test)
```

(How) Is this possible? Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This the mail answer from the author (Jesse Krijthe) of the Rtsne package:

> Thank you for the very specific question. I had an earlier request for
>   this and it is noted as an open issue on GitHub
>   (https://github.com/jkrijthe/Rtsne/issues/6). The main reason I am
>   hesitant to implement something like this is that, in a sense, there
>   is no 'natural' way explain what a prediction means in terms of tsne.
>   To me, tsne is a way to visualize a distance matrix. As such, a new
>   sample would lead to a new distance matrix and hence a new
>   visualization. So, my current thinking is that the only sensible way
>   would be to rerun the tsne procedure on the train and test set
>   combined.
>
> Having said that, other people do think it makes sense to define
>   predictions, for instance by keeping the train objects fixed in the
>   map and finding good locations for the test objects (as was suggested
>   in the issue). An approach I would personally prefer over this would
>   be something like parametric tsne, which Laurens van der Maaten (the
>   author of the tsne paper) explored a paper. However, this would best
>   be implemented using something else than my package, because the
>   parametric model is likely most effective if it is selected by the
>   user.
>
> So my suggestion would be to 1) refit the mapping using all data or 2)
>   see if you can find an implementation of parametric tsne, the only one
>   I know of would be Laurens's Matlab implementation.
>
> Sorry I can not be of more help. If you come up with any other/better
>   solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

From the author himself (https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/):

> Once I have a t-SNE map, how can I embed incoming test points in that
>   map?
>
> t-SNE learns a non-parametric mapping, which means that it does not
>   learn an explicit function that maps data from the input space to the
>   map. Therefore, it is not possible to embed test points in an existing
>   map (although you could re-run t-SNE on the full dataset). A potential
>   approach to deal with this would be to train a multivariate regressor
>   to predict the map location from the input data. Alternatively, you
>   could also make such a regressor minimize the t-SNE loss directly,
>   which is what I did in this paper (https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/AISTATS_2009.pdf).

So you can't directly apply new data points.  However, you can fit a multivariate regression model between your data and the embedded dimensions.  The author recognizes that it's a limitation of the method and suggests this way to get around it.

Answer (score 6):

t-SNE does not really work this way:

The following is an expert from the t-SNE author's website (https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/):

> Once I have a t-SNE map, how can I embed incoming test points in that
>   map?
>
> t-SNE learns a non-parametric mapping, which means that it does not
>   learn an explicit function that maps data from the input space to the
>   map. Therefore, it is not possible to embed test points in an existing
>   map (although you could re-run t-SNE on the full dataset). A potential
>   approach to deal with this would be to train a multivariate regressor
>   to predict the map location from the input data. Alternatively, you
>   could also make such a regressor minimize the t-SNE loss directly,
>   which is what I did in this paper.

You may be interested in his paper: https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/AISTATS_2009.pdf

This website in addition to being really cool offers a wealth of info about t-SNE: http://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

On Kaggle I have also seen people do things like this which may also be of intrest:
https://www.kaggle.com/cherzy/d/dalpozz/creditcardfraud/visualization-on-a-2d-map-with-t-sne

Answer (score 0):

t-SNE fundamentally does not do what you want. t-SNE is designed only for visualizing a dataset in a low (2 or 3) dimension space. You give it all the data you want to visualize all at once. It is not a general purpose dimensionality reduction tool.

If you are trying to apply t-SNE to "new" data, you are probably not thinking about your problem correctly, or perhaps simply did not understand the purpose of t-SNE.